# Parsing a weird string C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I got lots of data points from a .dat file that looks like this

```
 + (  0.00000000E+00   0.00000000E+00     //this '(' happens once per block of data
 +    0.99999997E-04   0.00000000E+00
 +    0.19999999E-03   0.00000000E+00
 +    ...
```

I have no control on to make the program that spits out this data more friendly for me to work with.

So far I got each line in a vector and I want to parse them up so I only have the numbers to work with, but I still want to keep the integrity of the .dat file due to another program that uses the .dat file as is.

I was thinking on separating each string by the space, but the spaces are different sizes (unless that doesn't matter) and placing them in a vector and getting only the data I need, but the first line of the data has 4 strings, where as the rest of the lines has 3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit:
I'm taking the original .dat file, tracing through it, and any block of data that doesn't meet my threshold, gets passed over. Any that does, gets written to a new file.
Everything with this new file must be exactly the same as the original file, minus the data I don't need, of course.

[JD] Edit per comments:

How would I parse these lines down, keep everything about it the same without removing anything about the line, and get the numbers so I can work with what I need to keep and what I don't need?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Are you writing anything back to the data file? You can always normalize spaces. However, if you want to normalize spaces and write them back you will have to make sure the *other* program doesn't get confused.

Comment: More info!!

Ok, so this .dat file I have simulates stuff. I made file with 20,000 simulates, but due to how gamma rays interact with the experiment, about 17,000+ of these signals were empty.
I want to trace through this gigantic file and any signal that passes my condition, will get written to a new file. Any that doesn't gets passed over.

Comment: I''m still not sure what the actual question is.

Comment: and you really want to do this with c++? I suspect perl or python would be much better fits for this type of task.

Comment: Okay, that's helpful. Now, what problem are you facing with the method you just described?

Comment: How would I parse these lines down, keep everything about it the same without removing anything about the line, and get the numbers so I can work with what I need to keep and what I don't need?

Does that help?

Comment: @JohnDibling: My interpretation would be thus: Create a smart filter that will pass through some large chunks of the file untouched, while dropping other large chunks.  Where the criterion for which chunks to pass is some moderately complicated calculation.

Comment: @dirkgently, I tried using the strtok function and that didn't work out too well. I wanted to get rid of the first "+" sign and, it did, but it also got rid of the entire string that contain "0.00000E+00". I'm trying to figure out how to get around that now.

Comment: I think that does clarify things a bit, shaboinkin, and I have edited your question to incorporate the clarifying question.

Comment: @shaboinkin: 1. You say the '(' only occur at the start of a datablock, should you expect a matching ') at the end and could there be several datablocks in the same file ? 2. Do you want to keep the data as a vector of pairs ? And if so, pairs of strings or pairs of float/double ?

Comment: @MatthieuM., Yes there is a ")" at the end of the data block and there about many different data blocks in the same file. And yes, I would like to have the data in pairs. I was planning on converting the strings into double.

Comment: @shaboinkin: do you also want to keep data blocks separate ?

Answer (score 3):

I would create a ctype facet that classifies `+` and `(` [Edit: and `)`, based on comment] as white space, then just read the numbers. Let's assume your criterion for keeping a number is that it's greater than, say, 1.0e-4. To copy the data to a new file, removing the smaller numbers, you could do something like this:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>

class my_ctype : public
std::ctype<char>
{
    mask my_table[table_size];
public:
    my_ctype(size_t refs = 0)  
        : std::ctype<char>(&my_table[0], false, refs)
    {
        std::copy_n(classic_table(), table_size, my_table);
        my_table['('] = (mask)space;
        my_table['+'] = (mask)space;
        my_table[')'] = (mask)space;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::locale x(std::locale::classic(), new my_ctype);
    std::cin.imbue(x);

    std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin), 
        std::istream_iterator<double>(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"), 
        [](double in){return in < 1.0e-4; }); // criterion for removing a number
    return 0;
}
```

I'd guess (but don't really know) that your criterion for removing a number is probably a little more complex than a simple comparison. If it gets much more complex, you probably want to use a manually-defined functor instead of a lambda to define your criterion. The rest of the code (especially the part reading the data) can probably remain unchanged though.

Also note that as-is, I've just written numbers to the output one per line. I don't know if you need to maintain something closer to the original format or not, so for the moment I just kept it simple.

Comment: You just have to be careful with the exponents that are in 1.0E+00 form.  But otherwise, the "Right Way To Do It"

Comment: @RobertMason: While it seems like that would be a problem, it's actually not (I tested to be sure --it properly interprets `1.0e+01` as 10.

Comment: +1: Clever, but seems *awfully* complex for what I perceived to be a very simple problem.  Perhaps I misunderstood the actual problem?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I should know better than to comment on code without compiling it myself :-).  Good to know!

Comment: @JohnDibling: IMHO this is more 'functional/declarative', so I think there would be more opportunities for the compiler or library to optimize.  And once you've done all the setup, the actual parse itself is just one line, is generic, and very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a string tokenizer to grab each data. Depending on the librairies you are already using, it could be very simple.

Otherwise, you can make someting very simple by using  [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/).

If you are using MS CString, you can code something by yourself like:

```
CStringArray TokenizeString(const CString& str, const CString &sep)
{
    CStringArray elements;

    CString item = "";
    CString strCpy = str;
    long sepPos = strCpy.Find(sep);

    while (sepPos != -1)
    {
        // extract item
        item = strCpy.Left(sepPos);
            // add it to the list
        elements.Add(item);
        // prepare next loop
        strCpy = strCpy.Right(strCpy.GetLength() - sepPos - sep.GetLength()); // get the right part of the string (after the found separator)
        sepPos = strCpy.Find(sep);
    }

    // add last item if needed (remaining part of the string)
    if (!strCpy.IsEmpty()) elements.Add(strCpy);
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can get each item at a time, using a file stream's `operator>>`, which will skip whitespace.  When you get to the column that will either be '(' or blank (eg, whitespace), check it and switch based on what you got.  If you got '(', do `operator>>` again to get the actual data.  If you didn't get '(', then you got data, because `operator>>` skips whitespace.

Here's a hopefully complete example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Inbound
{
    std::string  a_, b_;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream f("c:\\dev\\hacks\\data.txt");

    while( !f.bad() && !f.eof() )
    {
        string s;
        f >> s; // should be '+' -- discard
        f >> s; // either '(' or first datum
        if( s == "(" )
            f >> s; // get the first datum
        Inbound in;
        in.a_ = s;
        f >> in.b_;

        cout << "Got: " << in.a_ << "\t" << in.b_ << endl;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Got: 0.00000000E+00     0.00000000E+00
Got: 0.99999997E-04     0.00000000E+00
Got: 0.19999999E-03     0.00000000E+00
```

Comment: And this looks a lot less complicated :), I'll try this out. Thanks also